# AWS DAX and GSI negative caching after item creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have the table when I defined one partition and one global secondary index.

Then I create item and query it both by partition key and GSI. It works fine, in both cases I could get my item successfully right after it created in the table.

Now I have added DAX between my application and dynamodb table, and using dax sdk client to retrieve data just like in the manual https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-dotnet.html

And I always getting into negative caching scenario for my GSI query.
Meanwhile, query by partition key works fine within DAX too.

I'm receiving negative response right until TTL for item is expired. Right after that delay I'm able to get my item by GSI. I have tried to delay my query by GSI to avoid negative caching but even 120 second delay is making no change.

I can't find any info about that case in the documentation and would be glad for any useful information.

I could change my table schema to avoid GSI but I believe there is solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest including a Minimal, Reproducible Example of your code.

Interestingly, I can find nothing in the documentation that indicates DAX works or doesn't work with queries via a GSI or LSI.  But since DAX sits in front of the entire DDB service (not just a specific table) and since a GSI is just special type of table.  I'll assume DAX should indeed cache query results from a GSI.

If you write to DDB and then immediately try querying the GSI through DAX, it wouldn't surprise me to see nothing returned.  GSI's are eventually consistent after all.  Or if for instance you query the GSI through DAX to see if something exists before writing the item.

And given the way DAX works, you'd continue to get nothing back till the DAX Query TTL ends.

You should rethink you application design if you're reliant on a GSI to be strongly consistent.

For testing purposes, if you

- write to DDB
- query GSI directly till you get the item back
- query GSI through DAX

I would expect to see the query through DAX always return your data.  If that's not the case, I'd open a ticket with AWS.

Comment: Regarding immediate read, I pointed that I tried to wait for like 100 seconds and GSI item still didn't appear, that's what strange to me. I guess it ended up already in the negative cache somehow and I don't know how to prevent that behavior

Comment: Are you checking to see if something exists via the GSI through DAX before writing it?  That would do it.